# Rendering to a texture in OpenGL - Texture is just GLClear color

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, render-to-texture

I am using OpenTK so I can use OpenGL in C#. I want to render to a texture and then render that texture to the screen later. Currently I have a program that renders a green square to a texture with GLClearColor set to black. Then that texture is stored and rendered to the screen with GLClearColor set to blue. However, I can't get the green square to show up. I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

Here is my code:

```
int width = 300;
int height = 300;

//generate and bind buffer
int[] fb = { 0 };
GL.GenFramebuffers(1, fb);
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, fb[0]);

//generate and bind texture 
int RenderTextureTarget = GL.GenTexture();
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, RenderTextureTarget);
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, width, height, 0, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, IntPtr.Zero);
//^Rgba and Brga^ setting came from my texture loading function so this texture should be formateed the same as everthing else I render
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);

//set texture as colorattatchment0 and make opengl draw to colorattatchment0
GL.FramebufferTexture(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, RenderTextureTarget, 0);
DrawBuffersEnum[] temp = { DrawBuffersEnum.ColorAttachment0 };
GL.DrawBuffers(1, temp);

//setup veiwport and matricies 
GL.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1);
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();

//set clear color to black so I can see where the texture is being rendered for testing purposes 
GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

//render a quad that should show up as a green square on the black background with on corner at center 
GL.Color3(Color.Green);
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
GL.Vertex2(1, 0);
GL.Vertex2(1, 1);
GL.Vertex2(0, 1);
GL.End();

//set things back to their defaults
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
GL.ClearColor(Color.Blue);
```

Currently this is what I see on screen (Ignore the Text): [image]

So the texture is rending to the right position on screen an I know that everything is working well in the render to screen function because if I replace the id generated above with that of another texture, it renders perfectly.

My goal is to get a green square to show up on that black box.

Comment: Brrr, you're mixing modern api with the old one.why? I am not even sure this stuff is supposed to work.I mean passing the color from the fixed pipeline into offscreen tex attachment. Dude, try using shader to write the color.Do you run in core or compat profile?

Comment: I think there are two additional things to check. The status of the framebuffer should be FramebufferComplete which can be queried with GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer); and the textures have to be set up correctly. I am not sure on that but you could try to set the TextureWrapS and TextureWrapT paramters.